# How to properly add gradle plugin to multiproject?

Tags: gradle, osgi

I have a multi-project build.gradle:
https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/7c72399ede83b5f78dbae19582974f35

and this script fails with error:

```
> Plugin with id 'com.github.blindpirate.osgi' not found.
```

Why? Maybe buildscript {} should be outside allprojects ? How to properly add gradle plugin to multiproject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like plugin should be applied in each subproject's build.gralde but not in the root's "subprojects {" element. As here

```
git clone github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea.git
```

(plugin: "biz.aQute.bnd.builder")

Comment: Applying plugins in `subprojects {}` blocks works fine with the `apply plugin: '...'` syntax. The `plugins { id '...' }` syntax is the one that doesn't work in those.

Answer (score 6):

As you suggested, you can fix the issue by moving `buildscript` outside of `allprojects`. e.g.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.blindpirate:gradle-legacy-osgi-plugin:0.0.4"
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.github.blindpirate.osgi"
}
```

The reason this works is explained by the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies):

> For multi-project builds, the dependencies declared with a project’s
> buildscript() method are available to the build scripts of all its
> sub-projects.

This approach was also recommended by Gradle when someone asked a [similar question](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/buildscript-in-subprojects-ignored/2401/2) on the official forum.

Now to answer your question *How to properly add gradle plugin to multiproject?*. There is a better way to apply the *gradle-legacy-osgi-plugin* plugin, which is to use the plugins DSL e.g.

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.blindpirate.osgi" version "0.0.6"
}
```

Using the plugins DSL has some [significant advantages](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations) over the `apply` syntax you're currently using, so is generally the recommended approach.

Since you're working in a multi-project setup, the plugins DSL won't be compatible with the `subprojects` syntax you're currently using. I suggest one of the following approaches:

1. apply the plugin in the root project with a version, then in subprojects without a version. Use `apply false` to avoid the plugin getting applied to the root project. The [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl) have a full example of this.

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.blindpirate.osgi" version "0.0.6" apply false
}
```

2. create a [convention plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins) which you apply to every subproject

Using the `allprojects` and `subprojects` syntax is discouraged as it couples projects together, causing a problem for features like parallel build execution. Using the above suggestions help you avoid this legacy syntax.

Comment: I used legacy way and gradle said: "> Plugin with id 'osgi' not found." Does it mean that plugin found and applied, but is not compatible?

Comment: Which is legacy way? I outlined a few options above, so not sure which one you're referring to.

Comment: buildscript { ....

Comment: You can replace your whole build script with the above snippet and see that it works. I suggest working backwards from there.

Comment: the same - "> Plugin with id 'osgi' not found." I'm not sure that I used proper plugin

Comment: it seems like plugin should be applied in each subproject's build.gralde but not in the root's "subprojects {" element. As here "git clone github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea.git" (plugin: "biz.aQute.bnd.builder")

Comment: The 'osgi' plugin was discontinued by Gradle, that's why you got that error. As you found out, you need to use plugin `biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bnd.gradle` and apply it with `id "biz.aQute.bnd" version "6.0.0"`... see https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/biz.aQute.bnd